# How to save the response of Radio button in my C# program

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Screenshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nphv.png)working on to create a test page where one question is shown at a time. where four radio buttons to to take response and two button to navigate to next or previous questions. when i click the previous button the response is clear 
How can i save the response of Radio Button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class examination : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        DisplayQuestion();
}
public void DisplayQuestion()
{
        // get data from session object
    Examination e = (Examination)Session["questions"];
    // display data
    lblsubject.Text = e.sname;
    lblQno.Text = e.curpos + 1 + "/" + e.SIZE;
    lblCtime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    lblStime.Text = e.StartTime.ToString();

    Question q = e.question[e.curpos];
    // display details of question
    question.InnerHtml = q.question;
    ans1.InnerHtml = q.ans1;
    ans2.InnerHtml = q.ans2;
    ans3.InnerHtml = q.ans3;
    ans4.InnerHtml = q.ans4;

    // reset all radio buttons
    rbAns1.Checked = false;
    rbAns2.Checked = false;
    rbAns3.Checked = false;
    rbAns4.Checked = false;

    // disable and enable buttons
    if (e.curpos == 0)
        Button1.Enabled = false;
    else
        Button1.Enabled = true;

    if (e.curpos == e.SIZE - 1)
        Button2.Text = "Finish";
    else
        Button2.Text = "Next";
 }

public void ProcessQuestion()
{
    Examination exam = (Examination)Session["questions"];
    Question q = exam.question[exam.curpos];
    String answer;
    // find out the answer and assign it to 
    if (rbAns1.Checked)
        answer = "1";

    else
        if (rbAns2.Checked)
            answer = "2";
        else
            if (rbAns3.Checked)
                answer = "3";
            else
                if (rbAns4.Checked)
                    answer = "4";
                else
                    answer = "0";  // error
    q.answer = answer;
    exam.question[exam.curpos] = q;
    Session.Add("questions", exam);
}

protected void PreviousBtn_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ProcessQuestion();
    Examination exam = (Examination)Session["questions"];
    exam.curpos--;
    Session.Add("questions", exam);
    DisplayQuestion();
}
protected void NextBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ProcessQuestion();
    Examination exam = (Examination)Session["questions"];
    if (exam.curpos == exam.SIZE - 1)
        Response.Redirect("showresult.aspx");
    else
    {
        exam.curpos++;
        Session.Add("questions", exam);
        DisplayQuestion();

    }
}
protected void CancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Examination exam = (Examination)Session["questions"];
    Session.Remove("questions");
    //exam = null;
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewState is one answer, but you need to fully understand the implications of using ViewState.   Turning ViewState on will slow down your application and the more variables you push into viewstate the more the page loads will slowdown.

Each mechanism for state persistence has it's pro's and con's it's important to know the future effects / limitations of what you are doing.

To understand more about Persisting your applications state between postbacks I suggest you read through this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

To answer your question specifically:  Your code already shows that you are using SessionState.

Therefore in your DisplayQuestion() method I would implement a check against the current question Retrieved from the session and update the checkboxes checked state accordingly.

1. When your survey starts you add the questionnaire to session
2. When a page loads you retrieve the current question and response from the session state
3. Update the checkboxes checked state if the user has previously answered the question.
4. When the user proceeds to the next question update the users response in session.

Note: Session will only work on a single server unless you are using a state server or SQL server to store your session state.